# OpenCV VideoCapture not getting more frames

Tags: c++, opencv, video, video-capture

Does anyone know how to get OpenCV to grab all the frames from a video file?

I've been trying to just grab frames from video files (.wmv files, in particular), but on most videos, I end up with "nan" as my framerate and it only gets a single frame from my video and doesn't think there are any more. However, on at least one video, it succeeds and gets the right framerate. I tried to manually set the frame rate, but this did not work.

One thing to note is that it seems like the videos where it doesn't work are very short (~5 seconds long). However, I have not thoroughly tested this theory as I don't have very many videos (only ~10 videos).

The minimum code necessary to reproduce this is below:

---

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    VideoCapture capture;
    char* video = argv[1];
    int flag = arg_parse(argc, argv);
    capture.open(video);
    //capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 25); // Trying to set frame rate.
    std::cout << "frame rate: " << capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS) << std::endl;
    if(!capture.isOpened()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize capturing..\n");
        return -1;
    }
    while(true) {
        Mat frame;
        int i, j, c;

        // get a new frame
        capture >> frame;
        std::cout << "GOT FRAME!" << std::endl;
        if(frame.empty()) {
            std::cout << "breaking..." << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: One quick thing you could check : Do you have OpenCV's FFmpeg DLL in your executable (debug or release) folder? OpenCV does use FFmpeg through VideoCapture to decode videos. Either you built OpenCV from sources or you downloaded OpenCV binaries, that FFmpeg DLL is there by default.

Comment: I have FFMpeg there. Also, the code works with some videos, so presumably all the necessary things should be there? I'm just not sure how to make it work for every video.

Comment: I believe some video formats are handled basically in VideoCapture through native coding or simple codecs available on OS. Don't take my words on this but I do know that some formats are handled without FFmpeg. But, for most formats, FFmpeg is required. For clarification, did you manually copied "opencv-ffmpeg.dll" from your OpenCV installation into your executable folder? Naturally, adding that DLL to DLL search paths works too.